# why does log and exp matlab functions produce the inverse result?

Tags: matlab, logarithm, exponential

Why does `a`is not the same as `b` in `matlab`??

```
a = signal;
b = exp(log(signal));
```

if I plot a and b, the signal is not the same, any help?

Comment: What is `signal`? Does it by chance have negative or imaginary components? And what do you mean by "not the same"? In the sense of equality (I'm assuming that you're wiring in floating point) or completely different values?

Comment: @horchler signal is an example of a signal. and yes, it has negative values.

Comment: show an example in matlab!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logarithm of a negative number, `-x`, is `y = log(x)+pi*1i`. Thus when you apply the exponential function to `y` you will be left with a zero imaginary part (or something that looks like zero). Try this for example:

```
format long
x = -1;
y = exp(log(x))
abserr = abs(x-y)
```

Read more about the complex logarithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

There can also be inaccuracy due to floating point of course. The absolute error can be especially significant if your `signal` has values anywhere near to `1/eps` (or `-1/eps`). Try

```
x = 1/eps;
y = exp(log(x));
abserr = abs(y-x)  
relerr = abs(y-x)/abs(x)
```

which returns

```
abserr =

  11.500000000000000


relerr =

     2.553512956637860e-15
```

Note that the relative error is tiny. In [floating point calculations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) relative error is generally what we wish to control.

Comment: I had to read the "be left with a zero imaginary part" multiple times to understand what you are trying to say here. basically, exp(y) will be complex-valued where x is real. And due to rounding errors the imaginary part of exp(y) might not be exactly zero.

Comment: @sellibitze: Thanks for the suggestion – I've tried to update. The idea is that even if the the imaginary part is exactly zero, the output will now be complex (i.e., there will now be a zero imaginary part when the input was previously all real: `complex(-1,0)`). Thus it may look like the results are different. And even if it looks like the imaginary part is zero when printed, it may just be that it is very small.

Comment: Now, i'm not sure anymore what you tried to say with "be left with a zero imaginary part". I find it rather confusing even though I know the math behind complex exponentials and could have written my own answer.

Comment: @sellibitze: Taking the log of a negative number, e.g., `log(-1)`, results in a complex value. Taking the exponential of `log(-1)` should, mathematically, result in `-1`. But we're not doing math, we're programming. So, if there was no numerical error, Matlab would return `complex(-1,0)` (it actually returns `-1+1.224646799147353e-16*1i` which looks the same when printed). Because the the intermediate result of `log(-1)` was complex, all subsequent results will be complex. Think of "complex" as datatype rather than a mathematical construct (type `whos` to see if variables are complex or not).

Comment: You might read the documentation on [`complex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html). By the way `isreal(complex(-1,0))` returns false in Matlab.

Comment: I don't need to read the documention. I know very well, what's going on. I just find your 2nd sentence confusing. Maybe it's just me. But it does not seem to bring the point across well enough that you were trying to make. That's all I'm saying. If you want to keep your answer like this, so be it. tell me, if you want me to delete all my comments.

Answer (score 4):

horchler's answer is of course right – but I think it misses the *plotting* part which causes the OP's confusion. Since Matlab uses complex numbers when necessary, `log` is defined also for negative numbers, and `exp` should be the exact inverse of `log` – except for rounding errors. The numerical difference between `signal` and `exp(log(signal))` should almost always be very small. An example:

```
>> signal = (-2:2)'

signal =

    -2
    -1
     0
     1
     2

>> exp(log(signal))

ans =

                         -2 +  2.44929359829471e-16i
                         -1 +  1.22464679914735e-16i
                          0 +                     0i
                          1 +                     0i
                          2 +                     0i
```

However, the behavior of `plot` differs depending on whether the argument is a real or a complex number:

```
subplot(1, 2, 1)
plot(signal, '.-')
subplot(1, 2, 2)
plot(exp(log(signal)), '.-')
```

results in

[image]

Though the two vectors have a negligible numerical difference, the *plots* look completely different.

That is because if called with a single real-valued vector as an argument, `plot` uses the given vector values for the vertical axis and the vector indices (1, 2, …) for the horizontal axis. However, if called with a single complex-valued vector, `plot` uses the *real part* for the horizontal axis and the *imaginary part* for the vertical axis. I.e., the two calls to `plot` in the above code are equivalent to

```
plot(1 : 5, signal, '.-')
```

and

```
plot(real(exp(log(signal))), imag(exp(log(signal))), '.-')
```

respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `log` with complex or negative values, Matlab calculates the complex logarithm. This will yield unexpected results.

```
a = abs(signal);
b = exp(log(a));
```

will work as you expect it to (although the signal's complex part and sign will be lost in the process).

```
b = log(exp(signal));
```

will also work because it doesn't need to handle complex logarithms.

In other words, you have to make sure to respect your functions' domains. The real (as in non-complex) `log`'s domain is all positive(!) real numbers while real `exp`'s domain is all numbers. On the other hand, `log`'s image is all real numbers while real `exp`'s is all positive real numbers. That's why it works one way, but not the other. You're trying to do something the real `log` can't do, so Matlab switches to the complex `log`. While `exp` still reverses it, you will get complex results which are handled differently and can look entirely different depending on what you do with them afterwards.

Comment: Also, horchler's answer explains pretty well why it doesn't work with the complex logarithm. I just didn't get the notification about his answer strangely...

Comment: But `exp` *does* reverse `log` almost exactly for positive and negative numbers alike – there's only a tiny numerical error.